# Having problems aligning bullets left in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am a business owner (not a developer) who is trying to fix bullets acting (seemingly) randomly by:

- Displaying the bullet on the right side of an ordered or unordered list.
- Displaying the bullet on the right side of a list, with subsequent bullets appearing correctly on the left side.

The problem appears in Chrome. Firefox appears to be OK.

I have:

- Researched the issue across the web and in stackoverflow, but haven't been able to find a relevant solution.
- Tried rebuilding the page from scratch. However, the problem persists.
- Tried to fix using split design / code web development apps like DreamWeaver and Expression Web.

However, HTML continues to prevail despite my best efforts to fix.

My website was originally coded by developers (ostensibly) who knew what they were doing. So I am working with legacy pages and structure.

Sincere appreciation for any assistance. Other non-developer forum members will likely benefit from your answer.

Thank you.

I have inserted the nested ordered / unordered list code below.

```html
<h2>Private Equity Criteria</h2>
<p>To qualify for a Private Equity investment your company needs to:<br/>
 <ol>
  <li><span class="listtext1">Have a viable business model, customers, revenue, and profitability &#8212; with a 
minimum EBITDA of $1M - $3M.</span><ul class="listtext1">
   <li>That means: Neither start-ups nor early stage (pre-revenue) companies qualify for Private Equity.</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="listtext1">Offer a strategic business opportunity. For example:</span><ul class="listtext1">
   <li>Access to a fast growing niche market.</li>
   <li>Intellectual property in the form of patents, trademarks, and unique technology.</li>
   <li>Access to large, growing, and difficult-to-reach customer segments.</li>
   <li>Or similar benefits.</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ol>
 <h2>Strategic Investors</h2>
 <p>We refer to Strategic Investors as 'Private Equity Lite.' Strategic 
 Investors function much the same way as does a Private Equity group &#8212; with 
 the exception that there is no public investment fund. Strategic Investors 
 invest for themselves. Other than that, Strategic Investors and PEGs have 
 very similar approaches to investing in and growing a company.</p>
 <h2>What Private Equity is NOT</h2>
 <p>Private Equity is not Angel Capital or Venture Capital.</p>
 <ul class="listtext1">
  <li>Angel investors invest in start-up companies, rarely asking for 
  majority control.</li>
  <li>Venture Capital provides capital to early-stage, high-potential, and 
  often high-risk growth companies. Like PEGs, VCs also create investment 
  funds, and also take an equity position in the company, usually after 
  the Series 'A' funding round. Venture Capital is a subset of Private 
  Equity, but not all Private Equity is Venture Capital.</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: The example seems to render just fine. The problem is most likely in the CSS rules or some script on the actual page; without seeing an example that replicates the problem there's very little anyone can do to help.

Comment: I think you may be missing an accompanying CSS file / snippet to go with your answer. The HTML on its own looks fine, and if you click 'Run code snippet' you will see all numbers and bullets appear on the left

Comment: please attach 2 images, 1: the output appear in chrome 2: the output you want(you can design in ms word for just to take screen shot)

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Greatly appreciated.  I am investigating everyone's comments.  Need a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [actual page](http://www.navocate.com/private_equity.html), the paragraphs above the offending bullets have CSS of `float:left` applied.

This CSS can be found in the file `tvgcss.css`

```
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 18px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

Remove the float left bit and you should be good. Check your site to be sure everything still looks okay though.

**or if you only want to affect that page** add `style="float:none !important;"` to the paragraphs above the lists, like so (copy this, as there's an error in yours--the first paragraph is not closed):

```
<h2>Private Equity Criteria</h2>
<p style="float:none !important;">
    To qualify for a Private Equity investment your company needs to:
</p>
<ol>
    <li>
        <span class="listtext1">
            Have a viable business model, customers, revenue, and profitability &#8212; with a
            minimum EBITDA of $1M - $3M.
        </span><ul class="listtext1">
            <li>That means: Neither start-ups nor early stage (pre-revenue) companies qualify for Private Equity.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="listtext1">Offer a strategic business opportunity. For example:</span><ul class="listtext1">
            <li>Access to a fast growing niche market.</li>
            <li>Intellectual property in the form of patents, trademarks, and unique technology.</li>
            <li>Access to large, growing, and difficult-to-reach customer segments.</li>
            <li>Or similar benefits.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
<h2>Strategic Investors</h2>
<p style="float:none !important;">
    We refer to Strategic Investors as 'Private Equity Lite.' Strategic
    Investors function much the same way as does a Private Equity group &#8212; with
    the exception that there is no public investment fund. Strategic Investors
    invest for themselves. Other than that, Strategic Investors and PEGs have
    very similar approaches to investing in and growing a company.
</p>
<h2>What Private Equity is NOT</h2>
<p>Private Equity is not Angel Capital or Venture Capital.</p>
<ul class="listtext1">
    <li>
        Angel investors invest in start-up companies, rarely asking for
        majority control.
    </li>
    <li>
        Venture Capital provides capital to early-stage, high-potential, and
        often high-risk growth companies. Like PEGs, VCs also create investment
        funds, and also take an equity position in the company, usually after
        the Series 'A' funding round. Venture Capital is a subset of Private
        Equity, but not all Private Equity is Venture Capital.
    </li>
</ul>
```

And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: An altenative to removing the floats is just to use `list-style-position: inside;`

Comment: Ted: Your code (above) fixed the first (ordered) list number (1), and I have uploaded it to my site.  www.http://navocate.com/what_is_private_equity.html   There is still another bullet flying out to the right, toward the bottom.  ("Angel investors invest in start-up companies, rarely asking for majority control.")  May I please ask you to look at this?  And thank you for the welcome to SO. Everyone: sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: @KarlBuhl change this line `<p>Private Equity is not Angel Capital or Venture Capital.</p>` to this `<p style="float:none !important;">Private Equity is not Angel Capital or Venture Capital.</p>`

Comment: Ted: As you already know, that works.  Thank you. Very much appreciate your and everyone's assistance. Is there an online HTML / CSS video learning resource you can recommend for non-developers (like me)?  Thanks again.